# getting rid of buildDir deprecation

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

My personal preference is to override gradle's default "buildDir" from "build" and use "out" instead. Now for the longest time, I just used the expression

```
buildDir = "$projectDir/out"
```

but using buildDir is deprecated. I actually didn't find a recommended way to accomplish this same result, though I have seen evidence that this deprecation might disappear in a post-gradle-8.0 world. I'm using gradle 8.3, and I was still getting the deprecation indication in my build.gradle.

Answer (score 34):

To get rid of `buildDir` deprecation warning, update your `build.gradle` file with `layout.buildDirectory`

> The recommended replacement for buildDir is `layout.buildDirectory`.
> This property provides a more flexible and consistent way to access
> the build directory.

Earlier:

```
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now:

```
tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.layout.buildDirectory
}
```

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: Is this compatible with Gradle 7.x on Android?

Comment: @RonenFestinger Links were available at the time of writing, but since google keep modifying and updating the content, I didn't posted the link, which is exactly what happened here. Anyways, if you have any better suggestion, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @HX_unbanned It should, but I haven't tested it on Gradle 7.x. Also, is there any specific requirement for not updating your Gradle?

Comment: No. It is just to have clarity for proper dev documentation and documented test cases for this change in my product.

Answer (score 4):

I would write it like this to keep it as clean as possible:

```
layout.buildDirectory.set(layout.projectDirectory.dir("out"))
```

Comment: your suggestion and mine both worked within subprojects. so I'm using yours now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For at least now, I am using the following:

```
layout.buildDirectory.set(new File("$projectDir/out"))
```

I think it's ugly, but at least it works.